# How do I import a Drupal site and make changes?

Tags: importing-exporting, acquia-dev-desktop

I wanted to do something similar to whats asked in te below post.

[How to import a live Drupal site into Acquia Drupal Dev Desktop?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51449/how-to-import-a-live-drupal-site-into-acquia-drupal-dev-desktop/51454#51454)

I have the local version up and running by importing it to  Acquia Drupal Dev Desktop. Now am not able to modify the content.
 Could someone please elaborate the below statement that was part of the accepted answer for the question I referred. 
"Then use the Backup and Migrate module again on the local site to synchronize the database. "

Comment: In this context, they mean that you should use the backup_migrate module to import the database back into your newly imported site.

Comment: I did import the daabase and the site is up and running. But how to edit / modify the site content ?

Comment: not sure what you mean - why can't you edit / modify the site content now or is your question how do you edit / modify content in Drupal? What error messages are you getting? Are you able to login to your site through dev desktop?